# Ｈow to get the limit of the following integral $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^tR(r)M(t-r)dr=? $

Tags: analysis

Fix two functions $M(t)$ and $R(t)$ ． If we have $$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot e^{2t}}= C_1$$ and $$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{R(t)}{t^{-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot e^{2t}}= C_2$$
what is the limit of the following integral?
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^tR(r)M(t-r)dr
$$

or
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}|\frac{\int_0^tR(r)M(t-r)dr}{f(t)}|\le C
$$

---

I try to plug in these two limits into the integral but how about $t$ is small?

When $t$ is large enough, we have
$$
\int_0^tR(r)M(t-r)dr\sim_{t\to \infty} C_1C_2\int_0^t r^{-3/2}e^{2r}(t-r)^{-3/2}e^{2(t-r)}dr
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take $t\to\infty$, $x\to\infty$, $x/t\to0$, then
$$e^{-2t} t^{3/2} \int_0^t R(r) M(t-r) dr=D_1+E+D_2,$$
where the summands $D_1$ and $D_2$ come from the ends of the integral and $E$ from the middle:
\begin{eqnarray*}
D_1 &=& e^{-2t} t^{3/2} \int_0^x R(r) M(t-r) \, dr
&=& \int_0^x R(r) e^{-2r} (C_1 + o(1)) \, dr,\\
D_2 &=& e^{-2t} t^{3/2} \int_0^x R(t-r) M(r) \, dr
&=& \int_0^x M(r) e^{-2r} (C_2 + o(1)) \, dr,\\
E &=& e^{-2t} t^{3/2} \int_x^{t-x} R(r) M(t-r) \, dr
&=& \int_x^{t-x} \left(\frac{t}{r(t-r)}\right)^{3/2} (C_1 C_2 + o(1)) \, dr\\
&&&=& O(\int_x^{t-x} \left(\frac{t}{r(t-r)}\right)^{3/2} \, dr)\\
&&&=& O(2\int_x^{t/2} \left(\frac{t}{r(t-r)}\right)^{3/2}\, dr)\\
&&&=& O(2^{5/2} \int_x^{t/2} r^{-3/2}\, dr)\\
 &&&=& O(x^{-1/2}).\\
\end{eqnarray*}
So, assuming that $\int_0^\infty |R(r)|e^{-2r} \, dr$ and $\int_0^\infty |M(r)| e^{-2r} \, dr$ are finite, we will have
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-2t} t^{3/2} \int_0^t R(r) M(t-r) dr=C_1 \int_0^\infty R(r) e^{-2r} \, dr + C_2 \int_0^\infty M(r) e^{-2r} \, dr.
$$

Comment: But how to get $ \int_0^\infty R(r) e^{-2r} \, dr $ and  $ \int_0^\infty M(r) e^{-2r} \, dr$? Does it ok to plug in the asymptotic limit of $R(r)$ and $M(r)$ by $r^{-3/2}e^{2r}$? Then the first integral $ \int_0^\infty R(r) e^{-2r} \, dr = \int_0^\infty r^{-3/2}e^{2r} e^{-2r} \, dr $?

Comment: No, that's not OK, since the integrals depend on $R(r)$ and $M(r)$ for finite $r$.  You need to have more information on $R(r)$ and $M(r)$, other than your asymptotic limit.

Comment: If you knew that e.g. $|R(r)|\le L$ for all $r$ and some constant $L$, you could make the estimate $|\int_0^\infty R(r) e^{-2r} dr|\le L/2$.

Comment: Thanks! Also, we know that $M(t) e^{-2t}t^{3/2}\to C_1$ as $t \to \infty$. But why do we still have $M(t-r) e^{-2t}t^{3/2}\to C_1$ as $t \to \infty$? So $r$ does not matter?

Comment: Since we are assuming $r$ small ($r\le x$, $x/t\to 0$), then $(t/(t-r))^{3/2}=1+o(1)$, so $M(t-r) e^{-2(t-r)} t^{3/2}=C_1+o(1)$.

Comment: Thanks, I see. How to get the second equality in $E$? That is $\int_x^{t-x}[ \frac{t}{r(t-r)}]^{3/2} dr= O(x^{-1/2})$?

Comment: I expanded my answer to show this in more detail.

Comment: Can I ask the idea of this decomposing of the integral interval $[0,t]$ by $[0,x], [x,x-t], [x-t,t]$. For $D_1$, I think you fix $x$ and let $t\to \infty$. So we can use the asymptotic limit of $M(t-r)$. Similarly, we can do it for $D_2$. But for $E$, if we fix $x$, let $t\to\infty$, why can we plug in two asymptotic limits in this integral? It seems that you also take $x\to \infty$?

Comment: Also, how to get this step: $O(\int_x^{t-x} \left(\frac{t}{r(t-r)}\right)^{3/2} \, dr)\\
= O(2\int_x^{t/2} \left(\frac{t}{r(t-r)}\right)^{3/2}\, dr)?$ I am confused how to change this upper bound from $t-x$ to $t/2$.

Comment: 1.  $x$ is not fixed; as explained in the answer, it becomes large.  You can take $x=t^{1/2}$ if you like.  2.  The integral is symmetric, so it can be split in half at its midpoint, $r=t/2$, and will equal twice its lower half.